# How to write a sequence of MIPS instructions to divide the floating number at X by (-4), without using any floating-point instruction.

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips, ieee-754, mips32

I didn't understand how it is possible to load floating point into integer later diving with -4 without using any floating-point instruction.We assume that there is no overflow.I'am asking this question because i really lost in this Mips code.If someone can enlighten me, i will be very grateful.Also floating point is in X i need to write the result in X again.

```
    ##
## template for your assembly programs
##
##

#################################################
#                       #
#       text segment            #
#                       #
#################################################

    .text       
       .globl __start 
__start:        # execution starts here


    # say hello
    la $a0,starting
    li $v0,4
    syscall


    #############################
    # load the fp number in a fp register (just for printing)
    l.d $f0, X
    jal message5a
    # print X
    mov.d $f12, $f0
    li $v0, 3
    syscall


    # load the fp number in an integer register $t0 and $t1 (the operations must be performed on $t0 and $t1)
    mfc1 $t0, $f0
    mfc1 $t1, $f1


    # YOUR CODE GOES HERE

    mtc1 $t0,$f0
    mtc1 $t1,$f1

    jal message5b


    # store the $f0 result in memory
    # print X/(-4)
    mov.d $f12, $f0
    li $v0, 3
    syscall


    #######################
    #######################
    # say good bye
    la $a0,endl
    li $v0,4
    syscall

    # exit call
    li $v0,10
    syscall     # au revoir...


############## messages


message5a:
    la $a0,mes5a
    j message   

message5b:
    la $a0,mes5b
    j message

message:
    li $v0,4
    syscall
    jr $ra

#################################################
#                       #
#           data segment            #
#                       #
#################################################

    .data
starting:   .asciiz "\n\nProgram Starts Here ...\n"
endl:   .asciiz "\n\nexiting ..."


X: .double 10.00


mes5a:  .asciiz "\n\nX: "
mes5b:  .asciiz "\n\nX/4: "
##
## end of file fib.a
```

Comment: So you have the `double` bit-pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) as an integer in `$t1:$t0`, and you need to change the exponent and flip the sign.  https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html is single-precision but could be useful to play with, to see what happens to the value when you change exponent bits.

Comment: In general, software can do anything an FPU can do, just slower with lots of instructions. 
 e.g. software floating-point libraries like http://flip.gforge.inria.fr/.  But this case is special: `4.0` is a power of 2 so it's vastly simpler.  I'm not going to spoil your homework by spelling out the exact operation.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @PeterCordes. I am new in mips so if i ask a dump question forgive me :). I try a code but it gives 0 as a result.  `addi $t2,$t2,4 div $t0, $t2 mfhi $t0 # reminder to $a2 mflo $t1 # quotient to $v02 `

Comment: You don't want integer division on the FP bit-pattern.  It's in an exponent * mantissa format with a 2^x component...  If you have this assignment, presumably you've learned something about floating point before this.

Comment: So you want convert to integer, right shift 2, change sign?  Or manipulate the FP representation by flipping sign and subtracting from the exponent, then convert to integer?  What rounding mode do you want?